# jenkins fails to connect to git repository

Tags: git, jenkins

I can't configure the git repository url in a way, that Jenkins could access it.

under "Project > Configure > Source Code Management"
I set the Repository URL to
"git@store:repositories/testproject.git"

I get this error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h git@store:repositories/testproject.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied, please try again. 
Permission denied, please try again. 
Permission denied (publickey,password). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

the access with that URL works on a shell:

```
jenkins@dilbert:~$ /usr/bin/git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h git@store:repositories/testproject.git
git@store's password: 
4fd35a4f528e2f2921a52cfd03918b7cbde3d253    refs/heads/master
```

I am asked for a password and it works.

I associated the same password to credentials in Jenkins to "git/" and I also tried "git@store/". None worked.

Pleas note, that this is not about github, but about a local git repository.

update:

adding the pub key from the jenkins master to the build slave, helped to get the configuration working:

```
ssh-copy-id jenkins@dilbert
```

now the builds are failing:

```
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url git@store:repositories/testproject.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@store:repositories/testproject.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@store:repositories/testproject.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@store:repositories/testproject.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:735)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:983)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1016)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:484)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1270)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1751)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@store:repositories/testproject.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

store is the jenkins master, dilbert is the build slave. ssh from master to slave works.

```
jenkins@store:~$ ssh dilbert uptime
 16:06:21 up 3 days, 18:53, 13 users,  load average: 0,31, 0,38, 0,50
```

any ideas how to debug this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

authentication works via ssh. have you added the public ssh-key of the jenkins user to the git-user on your git-server?

let me know if you need instructions on how to set up ssh-authentication and i'll edit this post here.

**/EDIT:**

glad you got it running.
i looked on the official jenkins website for a detailed manual on the ssh part of the configuration, but i couldn't find any.

so here's a quick overview - let me know if this is what you need.

1. jenkins slave (the building machine) connects to the git-server
   (jenkins master)
2. building machine runs as jenkins user (e.g. jenkins@dilbert:~$ )
3. git-server runs as git user (e.g. git@store:~$ )
4. jenkins@dilbert public key needs to be placed in git@store authorized_keys
5. run `jenkins@dilbert:~/.ssh$ ssh-copy-id git@store` to copy jenkins@dilbert ssh public key to the git server

Comment: could you please explain which users ssh-key add to where?

Comment: the jenkins user should have his pub-key stored in <jenkins user home dir>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
this one needs to be added to <git user home dir>/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: doing "jenkins@store:~/.ssh$ ssh-copy-id git@store" get's jenkins to accept the configuration (that is an improvement), but a build on a remote jenkins slave fails. any idea?

Comment: good to read. unfortunately, my experience with git ends pretty much there... but i remember a similar problem at work.
i might be mistaken now, but you have to work as a user (e.g. Joerg Beyer) on the git-platform, right? please verify the permission there (you can change the users permissions in the web interface for each group they belong to). try to set it to developer for testing

**/EDIT:** you wrote remote jenkins slave - if it uses a different key pair, you need to add the public key to the git's authorized_keys once again

Comment: not sure. I updated the question. What ssh key do I need to add where?

Comment: `Permission denied (publickey,password).` still points to an ssh-issue. i think you need to add the ssh keys the other way around.
slave to master, so jenkins@dilbert public key to git@store authorized_keys file
`jenkins@dilbert:~/.ssh$ ssh-copy-id git@store`

Comment: now it worked. Is there a setup guide for build slaves in situations like this? that would make your answer perfect.

Comment: Part 2 of your question about `ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'` is also asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445619/jenkins-error-fetching-remote-repo-origin